# Declaring property C++ by reference or pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I want to declare some properties of a class. I am thinking of creating private variables for properties that I want in class.

And then exposing private variables by reference. But I have by pointer also we can pass the  address of private variable. So user of the class can modify the variable.

So which way would be better via reference or pointer as shown in the example below?

```
class ExampleClass
{

  private:
    int age;

  public:
    //This function allows access via reference
    int& GetAgeByReference()
      { 
         int& refAge= age;
         return refAge;
      }
    //This function allows access via pointer
    int* GetAgeByPointer()
      { 
         int* pointAge= &age; 
         return pointAge; 
      }


}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks for catching the mistake. I wrote this in hurry.

Comment: If you're giving full access via your accessors, why not just make it a public variable?

Comment: You realize that by returning a non-const reference, you are effectively violating the principle of data hiding? This seems like a really convoluted design.

Comment: Please don't write SO questions in a hurry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return by reference for two reasons:

1. Returning by pointer would suggest that `nullptr` could be returned (but it won't be). A reference can't be null, so the user knows they'll always get a valid object (assuming it is well behaved).
2. Returning by pointer would make the user of this function wonder about the ownership of the object being pointed at. A reference tells the user that they can do what they like with this object and they don't need to do any kind of memory management.

Whether you should be leaking the internals of your object like this at all is another matter.

Answer (score 5):

Better to do neither:

```
  public:
    int GetAge() { return age; }
    void SetAge(int age) { this->age = age; }
```

This way you can add sanity checks like age not being negative, and change the underlying implementation without having to change all users of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a get and set methods.

Get: Should be a constant method and return a `const ref` // `const int & GetAgeByReference() const {};`
Set: Take a `const` ref and return `void or bool` as needed. //`void SetAgeByReference(const int &)`